# Ethernet & WiFi Pi3b+

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet, pi-3b+

I have a raspberry pi 3b+ which I want to connect to two seperate networks.

I have an existing ethernet connection which works fine, and i am able to SSH/VNC to the pi over this network.

I have cobbled together a configuration from other questions on here, to attempt to get the WiFi up. My configuration is as follows:

WPA_SUPPLICANT.CONF

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1


network={
    ssid = "MYSSID"
    scan_ssid = 1
    psk="MYPASS"
    id_str="WIFI ACCESS"
    #prioirty=5
}
```

/etc/netowrk/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address w.x.y.z
netmask 255.255.240.0

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface wlan0 inet static
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
address a.b.c.d
netmask 255.255.240.0
broadcast a.b.c.254
gateway a.b.c.254

iface default inet dhcp
```

I created a file in /etc/default named ifplugd

/etc/default/ifplugd

```
INTERFACES="eth0"
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES="eth0"
ARGS="-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I"
SUSPEND_ACTION="stop"
```

Edited my rc.local file to ensure wlan starts up

/etc/rc.local

```
# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

#disable the ifplugd eth0
sudo ifplugd eth0 --kill
sudo ifplugd wlan0

exit 0
```

I rebooted my pi and no WLAN was found. I don't know if there's some config i've missed/gotten wrong, or if it's an incorrect p/w for the SSID.

Comment: You have NOT set WiFi country, have not specified OS (I presume Raspbian Stretch) and appear to be using obsolete settings in `/etc/netowrk/interfaces` (sic). I suggest you do a fresh install of Raspbian THEN explain WHAT you are trying to achieve.

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: *"I don't know if there's some config i've missed/gotten wrong, or if it's an incorrect p/w for the SSID."* -> If you try running wpa supplicant in the foreground yourself, it should provide details (they might already be in the system log): `sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c [/path/to/your/config] -d`.

Comment: One thing is definitely wrong: you cannot use broadcast address a.b.c.254 as gateway.

Comment: Hi *@Thom G*, you don't reply. Have you followed the suggestions? Does it work now? Are you still interested in help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to an existing wifi network on Raspbian os then you can use raspi-config quick setup

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Or if you want to setup your own wifi hotspot network with hostpad and dnsmasq then you can follow this

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use NetworkManager to perform the setup.

Steps:

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt full-upgrade
3. sudo apt dist-upgrade
4. sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome
5. sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd
6. sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd
7. sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
8. sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
9. sudo reboot now
10. Now connect to a wifi network using the new network manager you will find the the icon [image: NetworkManager Icon] on the task bar.
11. Select each connection and press the settings icon.[image: Select connection press settings in yellow]
12. Edit the settings menu to configure to your needs. The image is from selecting the mode pull-down list.[image: Configure WiFi connection Mode]

I've done this on a Pi Zero W with an external USB-Ethernet port to share the WiFi connection with a Ethernet only device. I've also tried this on a Pi 4 so it should work for you.

The information is based on the site:
https://dennymichael.net/2019/10/22/share-wifi-internet-with-ethernet-port-on-raspberry-pi-bridge/